Why Does Swift Require a Local Copy of Inout Parameters When Using Escaping Closures? (Learning Purposes)
Please note: This swift code it is intended for learning purposes only.
I've just discovered that Swift has pointers like C. I am trying to make this code work, and the only way I did is by making a local copy.
This one is working fine.
func myMult(_ x: Int, _ computeValue: @escaping () -> Int) -> Int { 
    if x == 0 {
        return 0
    } else if x == 1 {
        return computeValue()
    } else {
        return computeValue() + myMult(x - 1, computeValue)
    }
}


func myDelay(_ th: @escaping () -> Int) -> (Bool, () -> Int) {
    return (false, th)  
}


func myForce(_ p: inout (Bool, () -> Int) ) -> Int {
    if p.0 {
        return p.1()
    } else {
        let local_p = p.1
        p.0 = true
        p.1 = { local_p() }
    }
    
    return p.1()
}


// (false, (Function))
var myDelayedResult = myDelay({2 + 3})

// false
myDelayedResult.0
// 5
myDelayedResult.1()

// 1500
myMult(300, {myForce(&myDelayedResult)})

// (true, (Function))
myDelayedResult

Now, if I remove the local_p, I will get an error.
I am studying C, and C has declaring a point and dereferencing a pointer, and also the operator to obtain the memory address of a variable.
ChatGPT explanation:

Swift requires that escaping closures do not capture inout parameters because inout parameters are only valid for the duration of the function call. Storing an inout parameter in an escaping closure would create a potential for invalid memory access.

func myForce(_ p: inout (Bool, () -> Int) ) -> Int {    
    if p.0 {
        return p.1()
    } else {
        p.0 = true
        // error: Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter 'p'
        p.1 = { p.1() }
    }
    
    return p.1()
}

Now with that in mind, my question is, do I need to dereference p? I tried p.1 = { inout p.1() } but I receive an error.
Found this one Escaping closure captures 'inout' parameter but it still do not answer my question.
Any explanation would be nice.

I posted this as an answer(in a way still a question) but it was taken down, just wanted to continue the implementation and found some1 who would give a pertinent answer so I can  mark it as answered.
So here is the edit:

Even with this interesting looking functional thing without inout I still have to use local to a local. I'm not sure if there is a way around it. (BTW I still have no clue how to implement myDelay to be a reference thing e.g array, without using a custom one).
func myMult() -> (Int, @escaping () -> Int) -> Int { 
    return { x, computeValue in
        if x == 0 {
            return 0
        } else if x == 1 {
            return computeValue()
        } else {
            return computeValue() + myMult()(x - 1, computeValue)
        }
    }
}
    

func myDelay() -> (@escaping () -> Int) -> (Bool, () -> Int) {
    return { th in (false, th)}
}


func myForce() -> ((Bool, () -> Int)) -> () -> Int {
    return { (p: (Bool, () -> Int)) in
        var tuple = p
        if tuple.0 {
            return tuple.1
        } else {
            let result = tuple.1()
            // Cannot assign to property: 'p' is a 'let' constant
            // if used without a local
            tuple.0 = true
            tuple.1 = { result }
            return tuple.1
        }
    }
}

var myDelayedResult = myDelay()(){2 + 3}

// false
print(myDelayedResult.0)
// 5
print(myDelayedResult.1())

// 1500
print(myMult()(300, {myForce() (myDelayedResult)()}))

// (false, (Function))
print(myDelayedResult)


I did slightly change the function signature myForce(_ p: inout (Bool, Int) ) -> Int and myDelay(_ th: Int) -> (Bool, Int). Now I kind of can say p.1 = p.1

Whatever myDelay returns could be or could not be a reference collection, because swift has inout. Even if I make myForce return () -> Int I still have to use a local.

Swift is trying to stop you from shooting in the leg unlike C.

inout is not a "pointer". If you really want to use a pointer, that would be UnsafeMutablePointer<(Bool, () -> Int)>. That said, why do you want to do p.1 = { p.1() } in the first place? That doesn't change the effect of p.1.

How you expect p.1 = { p.1() } to work? If doesn't create copy It's looks like infinite recursion to me.

@Sweeper I used a tuple instead of an array. In an array, I would have to  use a type similar to this [Any], but my first element is a boolean, and the second element is a closure. Now, when it comes to my approach, I have no clue how to use an array to extract those values. Maybe I need to create a custom structure first... I have a few more weeks of studying functional programming before moving into OOP.

Somehow I thought that by using inout it makes a pointer to the argument I'm passing in, and even if the argument is passed by value, it kind of makes it be similar to a reference because you modify a value through pointer.

@Cy-4AH I think is because you assign a {value} to something that needs a closure. I think it's something like "unwrap this thing, and save it in this thing, and only use it when you call it".

BTW found this article the explains how inout behavior is known as copy-in copy-out or call by value result (https://sarunw.com/posts/swift-inout-parameter/). Also found this one on how to safely manage pointers in Swift (https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc20/10167/).

...what does this have to do with functional programming? I've removed the functional programming tag. Please don't add tags that don't fit your question.

@JaredSmith If it's not functional programming, what it is tho? Please explain in basic terms, I'm new to this. Thanks

@Adrian from the tag description: "Functional programming is a programming paradigm based upon building abstractions using functions, isolating side effects and mutable state. Executing pure functions is thread-safe." Your code has nothing to do with that, you use mutations all over the place. The "Functional" in this case means a mathematical function, i.e. a mapping of values to values, not just a subroutine label. The fact that you are using something called a function doesn't make it functional in the relevant sense. Your issue here (AFAICT, I'm not a Swift dev) is that you...

...want to reference a value stored in a memory address that according to whatever reference counting scheme Swift is using under the hood might not be a valid location for that value for the length of time that it might be accessed by that reference, declaring the local and reassigning seems to either rectify the reference count or maybe causes a memcpy under the hood? IDK that seems odd to me because it kinda defeats the point of reference counting but that's what the error message seems to be suggesting. But to settle this you really need an expert in how Swift actually handles memory.

@JaredSmith got it. So the only thing that would make sense is that in a functional programming language to use mutation you would built it this way, either if functional programming says that functions myst be pure plus other things, you would not have that many options for building stuff or you would make it too complicated? Am I right?

@Adrian I don't think so? I'm not sure I understand you. Functional Programming is a paradigm like Object Oriented Programming or Procedural Programming. It has different goals, abstractions, and design patterns than the other paradigms. You can write basically any program in any paradigm. You can also use each paradigm in almost any language, but some have better support than others. Your code is not written in the Functional style. This Medium post appears to be a reasonable intro, although again I don't know Swift.

...at least up to the part about monads, the author of that post clearly has no idea what a monad is. Everything else seems reasonable AFAICT.

@JaredSmith definitely, built-in functions are just great to have, I really like the idea of map, filter, etc. I'm still a beginner, I've built projects for maximum 100 - 150 lines of code, and the functional way with 0 mutation,  0 side-effects, and also recursion is the way. Now, I was just using Integers in my project, but I have a feeling that  if the project grows it will start getting n^2 harder, and harder to manage an understand. I don't want to think about how I would deal with String and other non Integer types... I still need to learn stuff tho.

Don't overstress yourself. Procedural is fine most of the time. Write procedural code for a few years until you start frequently running into/getting frustrated by the limitations. Headache first, then aspirin.

In the 6th comment I said "I used a tuple instead of an array..." thinking that arrays are reference types (I was thinking to python lists). Swift basic collections are value types.


I've just discovered that Swift has pointers like C.

Yes, but it's not related to your code. The near equivalent of a C pointer is UnsafeMutablePointer. As you've discovered inout is in no way a pointer. It is exactly what it says: It copies a value in, and when it returns it copies that value back out into the parameter that was passed. This means that there is, by design, no way to have a inout parameter live beyond the immediate function call. It cannot be captured because by the time needed to copy-out, the target might be gone.
There is no such thing as "dereferencing" an inout parameter because it is not a pointer.
(As is common, ChatGPT has given an answer that, if you already know the answer, is vaguely correct and yet is of no help. It is not a particularly useful tool unless you already have a pretty good idea of what the right answer looks like, and even then it is not very trustworthy. It is generally not helpful to post to Stack Overflow the output of ChatGPT.)
Your code can be written this way to get the "pointer" behavior you want. This is a terrible idea, but it does work, and may provide some insight into how the system works:
func myForce(_ p: UnsafeMutablePointer<(Bool, () -> Int)> ) -> Int {
    if p.pointee.0 {
        return p.pointee.1()
    } else {
        p.pointee.0 = true
        return p.pointee.1()
    }
}

I must stress that this is terrible Swift, and that it is very unclear what the goal of your code is. But this does do what your code is trying to do. Your code is absolutely not "functional." A core tenant of functional programming is immutability. So the moment you're doing things inout or var, you've already left the functional road. That in itself is not a problem; Swift is not a functional programming language.
But what you're doing here is both not FP and also not Swifty. Swift does not particularly like recursion; you can easily crash your program with it and it lacks key optimizations for it. The Swift way to do what you're doing is to build a struct (to represent a value) or possibly an actor (to manage mutable state). Passing around a tuple of (Int, () -> Int) is going to just make your head hurt in Swift. But, as I show, it's definitely possible.

ANSWER 1
I believe this is the kind of way I was looking for (instead of going towards a C approach), without initially considering that a custom type would be the best choice here. I have not yet started an OOP programming course, but this is how I understand the usage of a class in Swift so far (I chose a class to avoid using inout).
Also, this second field, I don't think this is how is done in swift, but it works in this example.
private var sec: () -> B

class customMutableTuple<A, B>: CustomStringConvertible {
    private var frst: A
    private var sec: () -> B
    
    init(_ first: A, _ second: @escaping () -> B) {
        self.frst = first
        self.sec = second
    }
    
    var readFirst: A {
        frst
    }
    
    var readSecond: B {
        sec()
    }
    
    func replaceFirst(_ x: A) {
        frst = x
    }
    
    func replaceSecond(_ x: B) {
        sec = { x }
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "(\(frst), \(String(describing: sec)))"
    }
    
    func toStringDeeper() -> String {
         return "(\(frst), \(sec()))"
     }
}


func myMult(_ x: Int, _ computeValue: @escaping () -> Int) -> Int {
    var result = 0
    
    for _ in 0..<x {
        result += computeValue()
    }
    
    return result
}


func myDelay(_ expression: @escaping () -> Int) -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int> {
    return customMutableTuple(false) { expression() }
}


func myForce(_ th: customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>) -> Int {
    if th.readFirst { return th.readSecond }
    th.replaceFirst(true)
    th.replaceSecond(th.readSecond)
    return th.readSecond
}


// (false, (Function))
var myDelayedResult = myDelay { 2 + 3 }

// false
myDelayedResult.readFirst
// 5
myDelayedResult.readSecond

// 1500
myMult(300, { myForce(myDelayedResult) })

// (true, (Function))
myDelayedResult


// 1500
let test = myMult(300) {
    let p = myDelay { 2 + 3 }
    return myForce(p)
}


With a struct myForce would look like this:
func myForce(_ th: inout customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>) -> Int {
    if th.readFirst { return th.readSecond }
    th.replaceFirst(true)
    th.replaceSecond(th.readSecond)
    return th.readSecond
}

With @autoclosure myDelay will look like this:
func myDelay(_ expression: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Int) -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int> {
    return customMutableTuple(false) { expression() }
}

// (false, (Function))
var myDelayedResult = myDelay(2 + 3)

// 1500
let test = myMult(300) {
    let p = myDelay(2 + 3)
    return myForce(p)
}


ANSWER 2
I've added an enum to make this code more approachable in Swift, but I've decided that I need a function called begin that performs side effects and executes only the last line as a return value. I'm not sure that "begin" is a very swift way, but here it is:
enum CustomTupleOrFunction {
    case tuple(customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>)
    case function(@autoclosure () -> Void)
}

class customMutableTuple<A, B>: CustomStringConvertible {
    private var frst: A
    private var sec: () -> B
    
    init(_ first: A, _ second: @escaping () -> B) {
        self.frst = first
        self.sec = second
    }
    
    var readFirst: A {
        frst
    }
    
    var readSecond: B {
        sec()
    }
    
    func replaceFirst(_ x: A) {
        frst = x
    }
    
    func replaceSecond(_ x: B) {
        sec = { x }
    }
    
    var description: String {
        return "(\(frst), \(String(describing: sec)))"
    }
    
    func toStringDeeper() -> String {
         return "(\(frst), \(sec()))"
     }
}

func begin(_ elements: CustomTupleOrFunction...) -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int> {
    var lastTuple: customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>?
    
    for element in elements {
        switch element {
        case .tuple(let tuple):
            lastTuple = tuple
        case .function(let function):
            function()
        }
    }
    
    guard let tuple = lastTuple else {
        fatalError("No tuple provided")
    }
    
    return tuple
}

func myDelay(_ expression: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Int) -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int> {
    return customMutableTuple(false) { expression() }
}

func myForce(_ th: customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>) -> Int {
    if th.readFirst { return th.readSecond }
    th.replaceFirst(true)
    th.replaceSecond(th.readSecond)
    return th.readSecond
}



let result = myForce(begin(
    .function(print("hi", terminator: "")),
    .tuple(myDelay(3 + 4))
))

// hi7
print(result)

let result2 = myForce(begin(
    .function(print("hi", terminator: "")),
    .tuple(myDelay(3 + 4)),
    .tuple(myDelay(4 + 5)),
    .function(print("Hello", terminator: "")),
    .tuple(myDelay(1 + 2))
))


// hiHello3
print(result2)





If you want to play with some code, here is an approach from a different programming language. (By the way, I have no clue how macros work in Swift, so I was using functions. Also, this style of macro is from another language.) The whole purpose of this next code is purely for learning purposes.
// This is really bad because it evaluates e multiple times.
func myForceCustomMacroFromAFunctionalLanguages1Bad(_ th: @escaping @autoclosure () -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>) -> () -> Int{
    if th().readFirst { return { th().readSecond } }
    th().replaceFirst(true)
    th().replaceSecond(th().readSecond)
    return { th().readSecond }
}

let result3 = myForceCustomMacroFromAFunctionalLanguages1Bad(begin(
        .function(print("hi", terminator: "")),
        .tuple(myDelay(3 + 4))
    ))


// hihihihi(Function)
print(result3)

Also
// This is also bad because a normal function can be used here.
func myForceCustomMacroFromAFunctionalLanguages2(_ th: @escaping @autoclosure () -> customMutableTuple<Bool, Int>) -> Int{
    let e = th()
    
    if e.readFirst { return  e.readSecond }
    e.replaceFirst(true)
    e.replaceSecond(e.readSecond)
    return e.readSecond
}


let result4 = myForceCustomMacroFromAFunctionalLanguages2(begin(
        .function(print("hi", terminator: "")),
        .tuple(myDelay(3 + 4))
    ))


// hi7
print(result4)

